# How to take a string, transform a decimal within to a fraction, extract part of the string, and compare it to a table?

Tags: sql, oracle12c

Here is the data I need parsed:

```
--TABLE: PRICE_LIST


ITEM_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(60)  VENDOR_PARTNO VARCHAR2(15)
----------------------------   --------------------------
.374 x 3 w/ph KLT-6            5506125
.4375 x 3-1/2 w/ph KLT-3345    5506124
.125 x 2-1/2 w/ph KLT-3211     5506123
.3125 x 4-1/2 w/ph KUR-44      5506127
```

Here is the table I need to compare PRICE_LIST.ITEM_DESCRIPTION to:

```
--Table: MATERIALS
--COLUMN: VARCHAR2(20)

ITEM_ID 
--------------
1/2 X 3-1/2
5/16 X 4-1/2
1/8 X 2-1/2
```

I tried this approach to try and separate them, but this will require a lot of work:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(VALUE, 1, INSTR(VALUE, 'x')-1) DIAMETER,
       SUBSTR(VALUE, INSTR(VALUE, 'x')+1) DIRTY_LENGTH
       FROM (SELECT DESCRIPTION VALUE FROM PRICE_LIST);

DIAMETER    DIRTY_LENGTH
--------    ------------
.374        3 w/ph KLT-6
.4375       3-1/2 w/ph KLT-3345
.125        2-1/2 w/ph KLT-3211
.3125       4-1/2 w/ph KUR-44
```

But now I have a column with a decimal that I don't know what to do with, and another column that has my 2nd fraction but other data I don't need.

Because only the last 2 values in the PRICE_LIST table would match, what I want is to return only this:

```
ITEM_DESCRIPTION   VENDOR_PARTNO
----------------   -------------
1/8 X 2-1/2        5506123
5/16 X 4-1/2       5506127
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you using such badly designed data? You should have a primary key that you can use to match, instead of mucking around with malformed data and sloppy string parsing and comparisons. You may want to buy a book or find a web tutorial on basic database design principles.

Comment: Seems like first part of description might correspond to diameter(.125==1/4 etc). And, yes, data should be structured. Currently it is very difficult to understand and use.

Comment: @KenWhite - I don't know the OP's specific situation. But, can you imagine a situation where this is existing data, in an organization that realized how idiotic their previous IT people were (just look at the data model), they fired all those incompetents, and instead *hired* the OP and others to deal with the mess? Of course, fix the data model, etc. How would you do that? Wouldn't you need to do **EXACTLY** what the OP is asking about? And if you needed help, wouldn't you ask here?

Comment: @Bohemian - It would help if you could explain what was unclear or "too broad" about the question. It is crystal clear to me, and probably to many who work with Oracle, or with databases in general. Perhaps it wasn't clear to you (and to Ken White); it would help to understand WHAT was unclear.

Comment: @mathguy: I'd create an intermediate table with a primary key that contained the two matching values. Look up one to find the match, and deal with the key as the ID. I certainly wouldn't be trying to parse text to find floating point numbers to try to convert to tractions to do text comparisons.

Comment: @KenWhite - Agreed, but the main issue the OP seems to have is how to split the existing strings. You would need to do that regardless of how you plan to fix the data model. The worst part is that - OK, you can add ID to the first table; but then you would match the second table (adding the ID as foreign key) by diameter and length, which is pretty dangerous; you would have to HOPE that diameter and length uniquely identify a part. (By no means an obvious thing.) But you would still need to go through the OP's exercise, if **all you had to go by** was the existing data.

Comment: @KenWhite - Rephrasing: The data is not currently in First Normal Form. One would need to fix that. But fixing that still requires splitting the separate bits of data from the existing strings. The OP is asking how to do that (as part of creating his JOIN, which is not the relevant part of the question).

Comment: @mathguy OP is asking for a small-program that does multiple things. This site is about atomic problems.

Comment: @Bohemian - nonsense. What the OP is asking for can be done with a simple SQL query.

Comment: @mathguy read the title. Count how many things OP is asking to do. It is irrelevant if it can be done "with a simple query". Questions should be about a single thing. The reason is we are building a corpus of useful knowledge here. The chances of a future visitor wanting to do this exact combination of things is zero. OP should ask how to do each atomic operation as separate questions, then combine them himself. Each operation in isolation is likely to useful *by itself* to future visitors.

Comment: @mathguy that is exactly the issue we are dealing with and thank you for being an advocate. Database was setup and maintained by someone who had no idea what they were doing and the company ran with it for 15 years. Now we have a mess on our hands.

Answer (score 1):

The data format is awful. Seems you need to create a custom user definied PL/SQL function to evaluate these expressions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION evaluate_me( p_x VARCHAR2 )
RETURN NUMBER
DETERMINISTIC
IS
  x VARCHAR2( 200 );
  expr VARCHAR2(100);
  y NUMBER;
BEGIN
  x := lower( substr( p_x, 1, regexp_instr( p_x ||'q', '[^.0-9 xX\/\-]+' )-1));
  expr := replace( 'BEGIN :p:='|| x ||'; END;', 'x', '*' );
  execute immediate expr USING OUT y;
  RETURN y;
END;
/
```

and then do like in this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7681/2

```
select p.*, evaluate_me( item_description ) x
from PRICE_LIST p;

|            ITEM_DESCRIPTION | VENDOR_PARTNO |      X |
|-----------------------------|---------------|--------|
|         .374 x 3 w/ph KLT-6 |       5506125 |  1.122 |
| .4375 x 3-1/2 w/ph KLT-3345 |       5506124 | 0.8125 |
|  .125 x 2-1/2 w/ph KLT-3211 |       5506123 |  -0.25 |
|   .3125 x 4-1/2 w/ph KUR-44 |       5506127 |   0.75 |
```

---

```
select m.*, evaluate_me( item_id ) x
from MATERIALS m
;
|      ITEM_ID |     X |
|--------------|-------|
|  1/2 X 3-1/2 |     1 |
| 5/16 X 4-1/2 |  0.75 |
|  1/8 X 2-1/2 | -0.25 |
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM PRICE_LIST p
JOIN MATERIALS m
ON evaluate_me( p.item_description ) = evaluate_me( m.item_id )
;

|           ITEM_DESCRIPTION | VENDOR_PARTNO |      ITEM_ID |
|----------------------------|---------------|--------------|
| .125 x 2-1/2 w/ph KLT-3211 |       5506123 |  1/8 X 2-1/2 |
|  .3125 x 4-1/2 w/ph KUR-44 |       5506127 | 5/16 X 4-1/2 |
```

This is expected to be extremally slow, the function will be called for each row of the left table and then for each row of the right table. So if the left table has for example 10,000 rows and the right table has 20,000 rows (not so much for RDBMS system), then the function will be called 10,000+10,000*20,000= 200,010,000 times. 
It's a cost of a bad desing - the data doesn't follow rules of [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and must be parsed on each access.

In order to make the query faster, **you have to create two functional indexes**, otherwise when you start this query you can go on a monthly vacation:

```
CREATE INDEX MATERIALS_eval ON MATERIALS( evaluate_me( ITEM_ID ) );

CREATE INDEX PRICE_LIST_eval ON PRICE_LIST( evaluate_me( ITEM_DESCRIPTION ));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this. I will test this out tomorrow back at the office and relay back. I agree the data is a total mess. It was poorly designed and maintained this way for 15 years.